# How to add DotNetNuke Forum to Default C# Web Site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to add Forum module to my Web Site , so I add dlls, components and modules and :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Forum.aspx.cs" Inherits="Forum" %>

<%@ Register  TagPrefix = "Nuke" TagName = "Forum" Src = "~/DesktopModules/Forum/Forum_Container.ascx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

    <Nuke:Forum ID = "ArtNF" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" />

</asp:Content>
```

This code doesn't works :) it's only a try , error here :

```
    Cannot register or retrieve components until ComponentFactory.Container is set
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot register or retrieve components until ComponentFactory.Container is set

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: Cannot register or retrieve components until ComponentFactory.Container is set]
   DotNetNuke.ComponentModel.ComponentFactory.VerifyContainer() +80
   DotNetNuke.ComponentModel.ComponentFactory.GetComponent() +36
   DotNetNuke.Services.Cache.CachingProvider.Instance() +35
   DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.GetCache(String CacheKey) +33
   DotNetNuke.Modules.Forum.Config.GetForumConfig(Int32 ModuleID) +91
   DotNetNuke.Modules.Forum.Container.ForumConfig() +65
   DotNetNuke.Modules.Forum.Container.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) +67
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.UserControl.OnInit(EventArgs e) +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +140
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +311
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +311
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +311
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +311
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +480
```

so how can add the forum from DNN to my page ? or how to fix this error

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNN modules rely on native DNN components so what you are trying to do is not possible. You could create a sub-site (in a virtual directory) in which an instance of DNN can run with the Forums module installed.

Alternatively, try one of the many .NET open source forums - [YetAnotherForum.NET](http://www.yetanotherforum.net/)